# How can I show the arithmetic mean is O(1/n)?

Tags: statistics, asymptotics

Particularly the sample mean, which I think should be $O(1/n)$, no?

The definition I have says, $f(n)$ is of constant order ($O(1)$), when there exist some non-zero constant $c$ such that,
$$\frac{f(n)}{c} \to 1, i.e. f(n) \to c, as \ n \to \infty. $$
So in this case $f(n) = n^{-1}\sum\limits_i^n{x_i}$, and $c = \mu$, the expected value of the sequence of random variables $x_i$. But then I get,
$$f(n)\to \mu,\ as\ n \to \infty$$
$$f(n) = O(1),\ as\ n \to \infty$$

Shouldn't there be a way to show it is $O(1/n)$? For example, if
$$h(n) = n^{-1}(h_1 + h_2 + h_3),$$
then $h(n) = O(1)$, right? Defining a another sequence $l(n) = h_1 + h_2 + h_3$, $l(n)$ should be $O(1)$ as well. But then, I can write $l(n) = nh(n)$. Then I could say,
$$nh(n) = O(1), \ h(n) = O(1/n),$$
no? Why can't I do this with the sample mean? I am not sure I can say $\sum\limits_i^n{x_i}$ is $O(1)$ as to do the same as with $h(n)$. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: If you take the average of a lot of numbers, you should get a number within the range of the original values, not a number which approaches $0$ (unless the range includes or approaches $0$)

Comment: The standard definition for $O(1)$ is that $f(n)$ is $O(1)$ as $n\to \infty$ iff $\exists K>0\,\exists n_0\,(n>n_0\implies |f(n)|\le K),$ which does not imply convergence of $f(n)$. See Big-Oh Notation in wikipedia.